# How do you use a python decorator on a function whose definition you cannot access?

Tags: python, decorator

Suppose that for administrative reasons I do not have write access to module xxx.

I want to do something like:

```
from xxx import yyy

@myDeco
yyy
```

which of course fails.

I think I can do

```
yyy = myDeco(yyy)
```

but is there a way to use the `@myDeco`" notation ?     Or is this only permitted immediately before a `def`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Python reference documentation, [Compound Statements](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions) section, it says:

```
decorated      ::=  decorators (classdef | funcdef)
decorators     ::=  decorator+
decorator      ::=  "@" dotted_name ["(" [argument_list [","]] ")"] NEWLINE
funcdef        ::=  "def" funcname "(" [parameter_list] ")" ":" suite
```

This is part of the syntax rules. As you can see, decorators are only applied before a function or class *definition*, which is what `def <funcname>` starts. It goes on, noting:

> A function definition may be wrapped by one or more decorator
>   expressions. Decorator expressions are evaluated when the function is
>   defined, in the scope that contains the function definition.

That said, keep in mind that decorators are really just syntactic sugar, and before they were made available the form:

```
func = decorate_func(func)
```

Was used instead. So if all you have is the function object in some variable, you can't use the decorator syntactic sugar and must revert to the second method.

Answer (score 7):

The `@` syntax is only allowed before a `def` or `class`.

Comment: In other words, you can only use the second form.